# Copy data from a sheet in one workbook and paste into a specific sheet in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to write a macro that opens an import file dialog box, has a user select a file, and copies/pastes the data from a specific sheet from one workbook into a specific sheet in the open workbook.

This is for a summary report that requires additional data from multiple workbooks.

I'm a little new to VBA, so I can't get it quite right. I can get the file to import into a different sheet, but not into a specific sheet. Any help would be appreciated! If there is a way to do this without macros, I'm open to that as well. Thanks!

Here is my current code:

```
Sub importDataFromAnotherWorkbook()
    ' Get workbook...
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim filter As String
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim Ret As Variant

    Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    ' get the customer workbook
    filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
    Caption = "Please Select an input file "
    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , Caption)

    If Ret = False Then Exit Sub

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Ret)

    wb.Sheets(1).Move After:=targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

    ActiveSheet.Name = "ImportData" 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post your efforts and that way you're more likely to get help.

Comment: this is only on a  macos then?

Comment: I've edited with current code. Thank you.

Comment: We're very quick off the mark and have already closed your question (I've voted to re-open), but it looks as if you are moving a sheet from one workbook to another. Do you instead want to copy and paste the contents to a specific sheet?

Comment: Copy and paste the content into a specific sheet in the open workbook would be ideal. I've updated the post with a little more clarity.

Comment: Somthing like `wb.Sheets(1).usedrange.copy targetWorkbook.worksheets("whatever").range("A1")`

Comment: That code is giving me an error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method" :\

Comment: what SJR posted needs to be in one single line (not 2). Did you adjust your sheet name in `worksheets("whatever")`? [edit] your original question and show the code you have used and which line produced the error.

Comment: Ah! Got it! Thank you! That works great! Is there a line of code to auto-close the opened workbook? It copies and pastes the data but leaves the selected workbook open in addition to the workbook the data is being pasted into.

Comment: `wb.Close SaveChanges:=False` by the way Google is your friend. That would be easy to find out yourself.

Comment: Apologies. I googled for quite a bit to find the answer to my question and only posted here as a last resort. As I said, I am new to this and trying to learn.

I also googled for this but could not find and answer that worked, but how would I go about copying a specific sheet from the target workbook? So say I'd like to copy only the data on sheet1 and paste it into the active workbook? I tried to use `wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2").Worksheets("Sheet 1).Range("A1")` but received an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ImportDataFromAnotherWorkbook()
    ' Get workbook...
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Set targetWorkbook = Application.ThisWorkbook

    ' get the customer workbook
    Dim Filter As String
    Filter = "Text files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"

    Dim Caption As String
    Caption = "Please Select an input file "

    Dim Ret As Variant
    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filter, , Caption)

    If VarType(Ret) = vbBoolean And Ret = False Then Exit Sub

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Ret)

    'copy into a specific worksheet in your target workbook
    wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy targetWorkbook.Worksheets("whatever").Range("A1")

    'close opened workbook without saving
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

#### Some additional notes

Make sure you know the differences between `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorbook`. In most cases `ThisWorkbook` is what you want and `ActiveWorkbook` is only very rarely needed (eg for add-ins):

- `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook this code is written in (it never changes).
- `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook that has focus (is on top). This can easily change by a single user click and therefore should be avoided.

Also you should not mix up `Sheets` and `Worksheets`:

- `Sheets` contains all kind of sheets (chart sheets, worksheets, etc) but …
- `Worksheets` only contains worksheets.